# CDO -extracting of specific region

Tags: extract, data-modeling, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a gridded dataset (NetCDF format) covering Pakistan and its surrounding areas, but I am only interested in the region of Pakistan itself. I am wondering if there is a way to extract only the specific region of Pakistan from the entire dataset using a shapefile and CDO.

```
raza@raza-HP-ProBook-440-G5:~/1month_pres$ cdo selname,precipitation gpm_monthmerge.nc temp.nc   
cdo    selname: Processed 9186354 values from 1 variable over 279 timesteps [0.12s 80MB].
raza@raza-HP-ProBook-440-G5:~/1month_pres$                                                                                                            cdo setmisstoc,0 -remap,pakistan.shp temp.nc masked_pak.nc  
cdo(1) remap: Process started

cdo(1) remap (Abort): Too few arguments! Need 2 found 1.
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
raza@raza-HP-ProBook-440-G5:~/1month_pres$ cdo setmisstoc,0 -remap,pakistan.shp,temp.nc masked_pak.nc

cdo (Abort): Too few streams specified! Operator remap needs 1 input stream and 1 output stream!
raza@raza-HP-ProBook-440-G5:~/1month_pres$ cdo setmisstoc,0 -remap,pakistan.shp temp.nc masked_pak.nc
cdo(1) remap: Process started

cdo(1) remap (Abort): Too few arguments! Need 2 found 1.
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have try these commands, but it is not working.

Comment: did you see this post on shapefiles in cdo? you need to rely on ncl, python or R to turn the shapefile into a mask I'm afraid, in which case you may as well perform the whole task in that language.  https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/6693

Comment: ...Otherwise you can do a rough estimate by cutting out a rectangular box that encloses Pakistan using cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in out

Comment: Agree with the above. You could look into my package nctoolkit. It uses CDO as a backend, and it offers a function called `open_shape`, which allows you to open a shape file and convert it to a netCDF, which gets half of your job done. Package docs here: https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/